# How can we prove that pure randomness exists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism, randomness

I want to know does real randomness ( no cause-effect law ), really exists?
And if it exists how can we prove it? because saying something doesn't have a cause is akin to saying we don't know the cause.
So what's the difference.
So, yeah, that's my question.
note: I'm talking about randomness in general and in specifically quantum randomness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proof (in the mathematical sense) of real randomness.   Rather,
we have a variety of theories that fit observation quite well (including
those of quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics) that utilize randomness.
If another theory comes along that does not include randomness, and which
fits observations as well or better, the randomness issue will have new life.

For now, time-dependent quantum mechanics (where wave equations predict
rates, but not specifics, of transitions) works very well, and would be
extremely hard to replace.   So, too, would the notion of 'temperature'.

Comment: Thanks, so we can say quantum randomness doesn't exist?

Comment: @IlyassBouada - no, you can't say that either. Unless you want to get into the realm of philosophy.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I really appreciate it!
So this is what I understood: If randomness exists we cannot understand it, but if we get more and more accurate and deterministic quantum theories then the possibility that randomness exists decreases, right?

Comment: @IlyassBouada - I'm not sure how a quantum model of electrons in metal  could ever be considered 'deterministic', because the conduction electrons aren't distinguishable.   A more deterministic theory, while possible, is not likely to be a minor adjustment.

Comment: @Ilyass It's not mathematically possible to distinguish a truly acausal [random sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sequence) from a deterministic pseudo-random sequence with the correct statistical properties.

Comment: @Whit3rd do you think there are any promising deterministic quantum theories? like a new hidden variables theory?

Comment: @PM2Ring So we cannot know if true randomness exists or not, that's baffling.

Comment: @IlyassBouada I'm at ease with the probabilistic outcomes of quantum mechanics, and have no ideas on where a hidden variable might be hiding.   As for statistical mechanics, I find randomness refreshing and invigorating, couldn't hope for anything better (it makes all the equations simpler).